# Android picker with full month name

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to find a way to make the `DatePicker` which shows the `year (number)` the `day of the month (number)` and the `Month as a 3 letters` abbreviation to show the very same but with the full month name. I mean that I want it to let me choose between January, February... and not Jan, Feb...

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this code , in your date picker

```
Calendar mycalender = Calendar.getInstance();
 mycalender.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: same comment for the other answer, this deals with processing the returning data which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");// also you can use: "yyyy-MMMM-dd"
String monthName=format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Comment: This is no what I mean at all. I want the user to see on the picker the full names of the months. I am fine with the way it returns the data to me.

Comment: I want something like the thing asked on: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892777/how-to-set-custom-months-names-in-android-datepicker  but without reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late post but it help others who looking for solution.

There is workaround through which can display full month name.

```
// get the datepicker view from findViewById and assign it to mDatepicker 
NumberPicker monthPicker = mDatepicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android"));

DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols();
String[] monthNames = symbols.getMonths();
monthPicker.setDisplayedValues(monthNames);
```