# Change DatePicker text programmatically

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using datePicker with the spinner mode display :

[My datePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XkGz.png)

How can I change the text that inside the datePicker and make it custom (for example - instead of "Sep" I want the text to be "Sep+current year" )

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892777/how-to-set-custom-months-names-in-android-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer here - so I could solve this with `numberpicker` with custom values :

**1)** I have created an array with my wanted custom  values

```
String mValues[] = { "those", "are" ,"some","values"};
```

**2)** Here is the method I used to configure my `numberpicker` values:

```
private void setNubmerPicker(NumberPicker nubmerPicker,String [] numbers ){
nubmerPicker.setMaxValue(numbers.length-1);
nubmerPicker.setMinValue(0);
nubmerPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
nubmerPicker.setDisplayedValues(numbers);
}
```

**3)** The Last step is to call `setNubmerPicker` method

```
 setNubmerPicker(myNumberPicker,mValues);
```